# How do I compile the time.c on Alpine?

Tags: c, build, alpine-linux

I don't like the built-in `time` utility in Alpine Linux and would like to improve it for my needs -- I want to edit the `time.c` and compile it to a binary. I have done the `apk add build-base` to install the gcc and have copypasted the `time.c` from Github, but when I do the `gcc /tmp/time.c -o /tmp/time` I get the:

```
/tmp/time.c:34:10: fatal error: libbb.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libbb.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~
```

So I copypasted it too but it relies on dozens more header files. I saw somewhere that I might need the `apk add alpine-sdk` and maybe it would also garantee version compatibility so I did it but gcc still does not see header files. Should I provide some `-I` flag?
What do I really have to do to finally compile my custom `time.c`?

P.S.: there is probably a SO tag for `time` but I can't find it.

UPD: I've copied the whole `include` folder but it says:

```
In file included from /tmp/time.c:34:
include/libbb.h:406:42: error: 'ENABLE_FEATURE_VERBOSE' undeclared here (not in a function)
  FILEUTILS_VERBOSE         = (1 << 12) * ENABLE_FEATURE_VERBOSE, /* -v */
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

but I can't find where it's defined even in the whole https://github.com/mirror/busybox

UPD: oh no, it's more complex.

```
/ # ls -l `which time`
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan 30  2019 /usr/bin/time -> /bin/busybox
```

Seems like there is no such thing as `time` binary.

Comment: There is much more to compilation then copying one file... The `ENABLE_FEATURE_VERBOSE` is getting defined by the build system, after you run `make menuconfig` from busybox. You better clone the whole repo...

Comment: Busybox combines all its utilities in one binary. This means it's not meant for anyone to compile any single file or utility and produce a separate executable for them, and as a side effect there's a lot of dependencies between the various modules and commands. You likely need to build/replace busybox on your system alltogether. (e.g. ENABLE_FEATURE_VERBOSE is created as part the build process of busybox)

Comment: If you change the way time work, you will break anything else that depends on it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that GNU time functionality is what your after, and BusyBox `time` being insufficient for your needs, just install the [GNU time](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/time) package which was recently made available on Alpine:

```
apk add time --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

When installed, it will replace the `/usr/bin/time` BusyBox symlink with the GNU time executable.

Comment: Seems like unfortunately it has the same problem as Alpine -- it prints two digits of time after a dot. Ubuntu and Mac OS print more digits -- 3. What I wanted to improve is printing with `%03` instead of `%02`.

Comment: @Nakilon I see. Then you can try your original plan to patch and build time, but this time using GNU time:
git://git.sv.gnu.org/time

Comment: Or try grabbing the source code of the exact Ubuntu package version that is working for you (with `deb-src` or from the package download page), and trying building that on Alpine